# Maintaining WIFI driver installation after an OS update

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have a laptop that came with a WIFI card that was not recognized by Ubuntu. I was able to install drivers to get the device to work. However as soon as I upgraded the system the driver no longer worked.

Is there a way to configure drivers so that they will still work after OS upgrades?

Comment: Install the modules in a manner in which they survive update... You didn't specify how you installed the module(s) (ie. *drivers*) but obviously did it to patch the current system & not survive upgrade for your *unstated* Ubuntu product & *unstated* release.

Comment: DKMS can be used so that the new driver is built when the kernel is installed and is working on reboot.  It may be possible to make it dkms if you show where your driver came from